# Enqueue Script only over specific WordPress core file

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

I want the way to register the script file only over one of the WordPress core files for example only over the `header.php` file.

Fore register the scripts over specific page and template we use one of these functions `is_page_template()` and `is_page()` But what we do when register script over `header.php` file?

Comment: You may be confused over how an average page is built.  Typically, every page loads a header.  Are you looking for how to control the placement of the script, such as footer vs header?  If so, the final argument is true/false for the footer.  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Comment: @jdm2112 no I don't want the placement of the script. I have a code within header.php, also I have the script that responsible to run that code only I want to register the script over the header.php

Comment: I'm sorry Shwan I do not understand your need.  For a specific page, the main template likely calls `get_header()` which accepts a parameter to serve various versions of the header.php file.  This is perhaps your question.  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header#Multiple_Headers

Comment: @jdm2112 for example only I want register bootstrap framework over the header.php and not other files

Comment: That's not how webpages work. You can't load scripts & styles over only certain sections of the page.

Comment: @JacobPeattie you wright I tried but because the get_header call in more files cant load the script only in the header.php file